# await for ListBox to finish rendering WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an `ObservableCollection<Customer>()` and for testing purposes i have simple for loop that adds 2,000,000 records with random numbers to search. When i click to load the customers this shows a nice spinner and works fine.

```
private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        bool result = DatabaseMaster.CheckConnection(con);
        spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        spinner.Spin = true;
        customers = await Task.Run(()=>DatabaseMaster.GetCustomers());
        customerListBox.ItemsSource = customers;
        spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        spinner.Spin = false;
    }
```

However i have a text box used for a search and would like to search through the customers and updated the view. i tried

`await Task.Run(()=>customerListBox.ItemsSource = customers.Where(X => X.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower())));`

However this through an error of The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

i try this however the UI still jumps as its updating the item source. any ideas or should i learn more of inotifypropertychanged ?

```
private async void search_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        spinner.Spin = true;
        customerListBox.Background = Brushes.Gray;
        customerListBox.IsEnabled = false;
        await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
         {
             customerListBox.ItemsSource = customers.Where(X => X.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower()));
         }), null);
        customerListBox.Background = Brushes.White;
        customerListBox.IsEnabled = true;
        spinner.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        spinner.Spin = false;
    }
```

Comment: Do the `Where` in the background task and only update the `ItemsSource` in the ui thread. It will still flicker when there are to many entries.

Comment: Note that `.Where(...)` is not actually doing that much. If you want to evaluate in the task, you need to call `.Where(...).ToList()`.

Comment: @grek40 it still freezes when i type in my textbox, because when it freezes it doesn't even show my spinner?

Comment: If you have that many records why not just use `VirtualizingStackPanel`?

Comment: @XAMIMAX i dont currently have that many records but wish it to be future proof, in reality it probably wont be more than 20,000 max. however i am learning and would be up to alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `customers` is just a local collection. Usually querying it in another thread makes little sense. However if you still want it, make sure that UI objects (`customerListBox` in your example) is used only from UI thread.

Like

```
var text = searchTextBox.Text.ToLower();
var r = await Task.Run(() => customers.Where(X.name.ToLower().Contains(text).ToList());
customerListBox.ItemsSource = r;
```

Comment: the UI still freezes when i add this, it freezes for around 4 seconds then responds. i believe it to be this line `customerListBox.ItemsSource = r;` causing the problem

Comment: @bish25 you probably tried the first version without `ToList()`. Try the current one

Comment: When i try that i get the error `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'
`

Comment: what type is `customers`?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<Customer>`

Comment: There might be a second part to the problem... reading `searchTextBox.Text` inside the task. I'm not sure.

Comment: oh, sure. that is the problem. I am updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

If You change your code to following it should work(because itemsource will be assigned in ui thread instead of inside of task

```
customerListBox.ItemsSource = await Task.Run(()=> customers.Where(X => X.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTextBox.Text.ToLower())));
```

Comment: it still freezes for around 3 seconds, it doesnt even show my spinner on ui thread which makes me believe its the UI itself slowing it down